# I am trying to figure out the stationarity of time series data

Tags: time-series, visualization, data-analysis

[image: customers everyday]

Here, this plot shows the number of customers served per day from 1 jan 2018 to 31 dec 2019.

I grouped the entire data by each month and calculated the average and variance per month.

This is the average
[image: average]

This is the variance
[image]

I also ran an augmented dickey-fuller test and got the following result

```
ADF Statistic: -26.031963

p-value: 0.000000
```

Since, the mean and variance do not vary too much, should I infer that the data is stationary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are certainly more tests you could try out but by [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Dickey%E2%80%93Fuller_test) of the test, you can conclude that your data is stationary.

On the other hand I would be concerned with your test results. Getting a `p` of exactly zero, and a test statistic value of way below -3 or -4  I would look at your implementation again and check if it's right.

Comment: The p value looks like a problem to me to, I should check it again. Thanks for the answer.